# Export CSV error "You cannot define a correlation name more than once" cause by SQL JOIN?

Tags: magento-1.9, csv, export, customer-grid

So I have narrowed it down to the fact that Magento does not like the JOIN when I am adding it to the collection. Is there anyway to make it so it doesnt duplicate the correlation name or whatever it is that is causing the error?

---

I've added an extra column to my customer order grid that will display the customer's street address, but when I try and export the CSV, I am getting the error "cannot define correlation name more than once". I've extended the Webtex extension "Customer Lifetime Sales" by adding a new function.

**Here is my function in the Model:**

```
public function addColumnCustomerStreetAddress($block,$after = null)
    {
        if(is_a($block, 'Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Grid')){
            $block->addColumn('street_address', array(
                'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Street Address'),
                'type'      => 'text',
                'align'     => 'center',
                'index'     => 'billing_street_first_line',
                'renderer'  => 'Webtex_CustomerLifetimeSales_Block_Catalog_Product_Renderer_Street'
            ));
            if($after)$block->addColumnOrder($this->getName(), $after);
        }
        return $block;
    }
```

**Here is my join in the Observer that grabs the customers street address:**

```
public function addAttributesToCollection($observer)
    {
        /** @var $collection  Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer_Collection */
        $collection = $observer->getCollection();
        if(is_a($collection,'Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer_Collection'))
            $collection->addAttributeToSelect('total_spent')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('total_in_cart')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('orders_count')
                ->joinAttribute('billing_street_first_line', 'customer_address/street', 'default_billing', null)
                ->addAttributeToSelect('last_order_date');
    }
```

**And finally, here is my renderer:**

```
class Webtex_CustomerLifetimeSales_Block_Catalog_Product_Renderer_Street extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{
    public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    {
        $value = $row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex());
        return $value;
    }
}
```

Now this works fine when displaying the street address in the actual grid, but when I try and export to CSV I get this error:

```
    a:5:{i:0;s:75:"You cannot define a correlation name 'at_my_shipping_street' more than once";i:1;s:2870:"#0 /opt2/sites/mySite/lib/Varien/Db/Select.php(281): Zend_Db_Select->_join('left join', Array, '(`at_my_shippin...', Array, NULL)
#1 /opt2/sites/mySite/lib/Zend/Db/Select.php(357): Varien_Db_Select->_join('left join', Array, '(`at_my_shippin...', Array, NULL)
#2 /opt2/sites/mySite/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(1348): Zend_Db_Select->joinLeft(Array, '(`at_my_shippin...', Array)
#3 /opt2/sites/mySite/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(1315): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->_joinAttributeToSelect('joinLeft', Object(Mage_Customer_Model_Attribute), 'at_my_shipping_...', Array, 'my_shipping_str...', 'at_my_shipping_...')
#4 /opt2/sites/mySite/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(668): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->_addAttributeJoin('my_shipping_str...', 'left')
#5 /opt2/sites/mySite/app/code/local/Webtex/CustomerLifetimeSales/Model/Observer.php(153): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->joinAttribute('my_shipping_str...', 'customer_addres...', 'default_billing', NULL, 'left')
#6 /opt2/sites/mySite/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Webtex_CustomerLifetimeSales_Model_Observer->addAttributesToCollection(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#7 /opt2/sites/mySite/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Webtex_CustomerLifetimeSales_Model_Observer), 'addAttributesTo...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#8 /opt2/sites/mySite/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('eav_collection_...', Array)
#9 /opt2/sites/mySite/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(863): Mage::dispatchEvent('eav_collection_...', Array)
#10 /opt2/sites/mySite/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(951): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->load()
#11 /opt2/sites/mySite/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(1008): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_exportIterateCollection('_exportCsvItem', Array)
#12 /opt2/sites/mySite/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/CustomerController.php(380): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->getCsvFile()
#13 /opt2/sites/mySite/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_CustomerController->exportCsvAction()
#14 /opt2/sites/mySite/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('exportCsv')
#15 /opt2/sites/mySite/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#16 /opt2/sites/mySite/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#17 /opt2/sites/mySite/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#18 /opt2/sites/mySite/index.php(91): Mage::run('', 'store')
#19 {main}";s:3:"url";s:83:"/mySite/index.php/myAdminArea/customer/exportCsv/key/be8bdec3e90d2a19c7d05bd23470542b/";s:11:"script_name";s:17:"/mySite/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

---

**EDIT2:**

Here is the entire model Field class, with my modification at the bottom:

```
class Webtex_CustomerLifetimeSales_Model_Field extends Webtex_Core_Model_Core
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('clSales/field');
    }

    public function __call($method, $arguments)
    {
        if (substr($method, 0, 9) == 'addColumn') return $this->addCustomColumn($arguments[0],$arguments[1]);
        else return parent::__call($method, $arguments);
    }

    protected function addCustomColumn($block,$after = null)
    {
        if(is_a($block,'Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Grid'))
        {
            $columnArray = array();
            $columnArray['header'] = Mage::helper('customer')->__($this->getHelper());
            $columnArray['index'] = $this->getIndex();
            $this->getWidth() != 0 ? $columnArray['width'] = $this->getWidth() : '';
            $this->getType() != '' ? $columnArray['type'] = $this->getType() : '';
            if($this->getType() == "price")
                $columnArray['currency_code'] = Mage::app()->getStore()->getBaseCurrency()->getCode();
            $block->addColumn($this->getName(), $columnArray);
            if($after)$block->addColumnsOrder($this->getName(),$after);

        }
        return $block;

    }

    public function addColumnLastOrderDate($block,$after = null)
    {
        if(is_a($block,'Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Grid')){
            $block->addColumn('last_order_date', array(
                'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Last Order Date'),
                'type'      => 'datetime',
                'align'     => 'center',
                'index'     => 'last_order_date',
                'gmtoffset' => true
            ));

            if($after)$block->addColumnsOrder($this->getName(),$after);

        }
        return $block;
    }

    public function addColumnStreetAddress($block,$after = null)
    {
        if(is_a($block, 'Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Grid')){
            $block->addColumn('street_address', array(
                'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Street Address'),
                'type'      => 'text',
                'align'     => 'center',
                'index'     => 'customer_address',
                'renderer'  => 'Webtex_CustomerLifetimeSales_Block_Catalog_Product_Renderer_Street'
            ));
        }
        return $block;
    }

}
```

And here is the Observer with my JOIN in the function addAttributesToCollection:

```
class Webtex_CustomerLifetimeSales_Model_Observer
{

    public function cartSaveAfterHandler($event)
    {
        try {
            $customer = $event->getCart()->getQuote()->getCustomer();
            if ($customer->getId()) {
                $customer->setTotalInCart($event->getCart()->getQuote()->getGrandTotal());
                $customer->save();
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            if (Mage::getIsDeveloperMode()) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
            Mage::logException($e);
        }
    }

    public function orderSaveAfterHandler($event)
    {
        try {
            $customer = $event->getQuote()->getCustomer();
            if ($customer->getId()) {
                $customer->setTotalInCart(0);
                $customer->save();
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            if (Mage::getIsDeveloperMode()) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
            Mage::logException($e);
        }
    }

    public function invoicePayHandler($event)
    {
        try {
            if ($event->getInvoice()->getCustomerId()) {
                $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($event->getInvoice()->getCustomerId());
                $customer->getAttribute('total_spent');
                $customer->setTotalSpent($customer->getTotalSpent() + $event->getInvoice()->getGrandTotal());
                $customer->save();
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            if (Mage::getIsDeveloperMode()) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
            Mage::logException($e);
        }
    }

    public function invoiceRefundHandler($event)
    {
        try {
            if ($event->getCreditmemo()->getCustomerId()) {
                $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($event->getCreditmemo()->getCustomerId());
                $customer->getAttribute('total_spent');
                $customer->setTotalSpent($customer->getTotalSpent() - $event->getCreditmemo()->getGrandTotal());
                $customer->save();
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            if (Mage::getIsDeveloperMode()) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
            Mage::logException($e);
        }
    }

    public function ordersChangeHandler($event)
    {
        try {
            if ($event->getOrder()->getCustomerId()){
                $data = $event->getDataObject()->getData();
                $originData = $event->getDataObject()->getOrigData();
                switch($data['state']){
                    case 'closed':
                        if(isset($originData) && 'complete'==$originData['state']){
                            $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($event->getOrder()->getCustomerId());
                            $customer->getAttribute('total_spent');
                            $customer->getAttribute('orders_count');
                            $customer->setTotalSpent($customer->getTotalSpent() - $data['base_total_refunded']);
                            $customer->setOrdersCount($customer->getOrdersCount() - 1);
                            $customer->save();
                        }
                        break;
                    case 'complete':
                        if(!isset($originData) || 'complete'!=$originData['state']){
                            $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($event->getOrder()->getCustomerId());
                            $customer->getAttribute('total_spent');
                            $customer->getAttribute('orders_count');
                            $customer->setTotalSpent($customer->getTotalSpent() + $data['base_total_paid']);
                            $customer->setOrdersCount($customer->getOrdersCount() + 1);
                            $customer->setLastOrderDate($data['updated_at']);
                            $customer->save();
                        }
                        break;

                }
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            if (Mage::getIsDeveloperMode()) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
            Mage::logException($e);
        }
    }


    public function addAttributesToCollection($observer)
    {
        /** @var $collection  Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer_Collection */
        $customerStreetCollection = $observer->getCollection();
        if(is_a($customerStreetCollection, 'Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer_Collection'))
        {
            $customerStreetCollection->joinAttribute('customer_address', 'customer_address/street', 'default_billing', null, 'left');
        }
        $collection = $observer->getCollection();
        if(is_a($collection,'Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer_Collection'))
            $collection->addAttributeToSelect('total_spent')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('total_in_cart')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('orders_count')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('last_order_date')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('street_address');
    }

    public function addColumnsInGrid($observer)
    {
        $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();
        if(is_a($block,'Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Grid')
            && $block->getRequest()->getControllerName() == 'customer')
        {
            /** @var $block Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Grid */
            /** @var $addFieldsCollection Webtex_CustomerLifetimeSales_Model_Resource_Field_Collection */
            $addFieldsCollection = Mage::getModel('clSales/field')->getCollection();
            $addFieldsCollection->addFieldToFilter('native',0)
                ->addFieldToFilter('is_show',1)
                ->addFieldToFilter('editable',1);

            $lastNative = Mage::getModel('clSales/field')->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter('is_show',1)
            ->addFieldToFilter('native',1)
            ->addFieldToFilter('editable',1)
            ->setOrder('entity_id',Varien_Data_Collection::SORT_ORDER_DESC);
            if(Mage::app()->isSingleStoreMode())$lastNative->addFieldToFilter('name',array('neq'=>'website_id'));
            $lastNative = $lastNative->getFirstItem();

            $filter = new Zend_Filter_Word_UnderscoreToCamelCase();

            foreach($addFieldsCollection as $field)
                $block = call_user_func(array($field, 'addColumn' . $filter->filter($field->getName())), $block, $lastNative->getName());




        }
    }

    public function removeColumnsFromGrid($observer)
    {
        $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();
        if(is_a($block,'Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Grid')
            && $block->getRequest()->getControllerName() == 'customer')
        {
            /** @var $block Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Grid */
            /** @var $removeFieldsCollection Webtex_CustomerLifetimeSales_Model_Resource_Field_Collection */
            $removeFieldsCollection = Mage::getModel('clSales/field')->getCollection();
            $removeFieldsCollection->addFieldToFilter('native',1)
                                    ->addFieldToFilter('is_show',0)
                                    ->addFieldToFilter('editable',1);

            foreach($removeFieldsCollection as $field)
                $block->removeColumn($field->getName());


        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you provide your observer and model files?

Comment: Added the observer and model in a new edit at the bottom. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This error occurs when that column is set more than once. Probably when you export the data, it already calls this column for the second time. In grid class of your model, try using the following function:

```
protected function _afterLoadCollection() {
    if(!$this->_isExport) {
        $this->removeColumn('at_my_shipping_street');
    }
}
```

**Note**: _afterLoadCollection is used in `_prepareCollection()` function, so if you override this function in your grid class, eventually you may have to change it as well.

Comment: I'm getting an error "Undefined property: Webtex_CustomerLifetimeSales_Model_Observer::$_isExport"

Guess that _isExport is not available to this class?

Comment: Also, this extension is not using an Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php class to override the core

Comment: What grid class it uses to override the core? _isExport exists in Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, the only place I can see them adding/editing the grid is within the Observer.php file, but there is no direct override of Grid.php

Comment: So I have a new update, When I limit the group of customers to 1000, it will export no problem, but once I cross that threshold, I will get the "cannot define a correlation..." error.

Comment: Magento defaults to 1000 records when doing csv exports.  So only add the columns if Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl() does not contain exportCsv OR Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl() does contain exportCsv and $collection->getCurPage() == 1.

Answer (score 1):

It is because Magento will perform the `$collection->load()` method
every 1000 lines for the export. In your observer you should check
first if columns are already declared with
`$collection->getSelect()->getPart("column")`, it gives you an array that
will contain the columns and you should just check if the column is in
there.